# Show ageing data and then Email using SharePoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, sharepoint-rest-api

I have created one **Ageing column** and one **TodayDate column** in SharePoint list.

I want to update **Ageing** column with number of days based on difference between last **Modified** and **TodayDate** column for all the items. But there is no way to use calculated column as we cant get Today's date in the formula.

So how i can achieve that with workflow so that **TodayDate** column will be updated daily with today's date and based on that **Ageing** column will get the updated value automatically. Also when **Ageing** column will have value more than 7 then Email should trigger to a user.

Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a SharePoint Designer workflow to set the TodayDate column to Today's date, then use **Information Management Policy settings** ->**Retention stage** at the list settings level to trigger the workflow daily based on your requirement.
[image]
[Lesson: Information Management Policy](https://www.webucator.com/tutorial/advanced-microsoft-sharepoint/information-management-policy.cfm)